# Issue connecting note 10 to windows 10

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, usb, connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

My note 10 screen does not display anything. So I cannot see any note 10 pop up prompts. In windows 10 settings bluetooth and other devices. When I connect my note 9 it gives the name of my phone that I choose. When I connect my note 10 it says samsung android. When I turn off my note 9 and connect it does not say anything. Based on this I can assume my note 10 is on. But why does my pc not show real name of my note 10? Why generic?

Comment: Have configured a lock screen PIN/password? If yes you have to enter it after a reboot to make the phone fully finish booting (by default the device boots to a state where some parts of the system are already booted but all user-related apps and some settings are not yet ready). May be this is the reason.

Comment: @Robert i was thinking that but when I tried that using my note 9 it still said my phones actual name. But maybe because it had already done that before and I never connected my note 10 before. So maybe my win 10 has not recognized it from before